# Why I can not start harmony mode by "node --harmony test.js" from command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

**The problem is：**

```
longhao33@hePC:~$ node --harmony test.js 
/home/longhao33/test.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { let str = 'es666666666666';
                                                              ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

**But "let" is supported when:**（So strange！）

```
longhao33@hePC:~$ node --harmony
> let str = 'es66666666666'
undefined
> str
'es66666666666'
```

1. system:ubuntu 14.04LTS 64bit
2. node:V4.1.1 (Installed by nvm,which is installed at $HOME)
3. content of test.js:

   let str = 'es666666666666';
   console.log(str);

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing `'use strict';` at the top of your `test.js` (as indicated by the error message).

It works in the REPL because [`'use strict';` is automatically included during code evaluation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/fcfd87d7e11ba238dbc4d333cefaeb84b6afe7dc/lib/repl.js#L133-L135).